# Java Encrypt And Save Vector to File

Tags: java, encryption, vector

I have a vector of user passwords. I would like to save this vector to a file and encrypt it. Then load and decrypt the file to get the passwords. I would like my users to enter a pass phrase to decrypt the files. Which algorithm should i choose? and How can i encrypt the vector before writing the file?

Answer (score 3):

Encryption in Java is done using the [Java Cryptography Architecture](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) (doc contains example code). As for which algorithm to use, AES should be fine.

However, don't use `Vector` - it's utterly outdated and should be replaced with `ArrayList` (this has nothing to do with cryptography, but using `Vector` marks you as someone who's been learning Java from 12 year old books).

Comment: It's a generalization, but there is a school of thought that says "Typing the letters A-E-S into your code? You're doing it wrong!": http://www.securityfocus.com/blogs/2009 ...but I guess someone has to. Vector makes me wish there were levels of deprecation - maybe we need a new annotation that says "this isn't broken, but there are better ways than this."

Comment: Holy fscking sh*t! What kind of person writes a 15 page movie script to make a 2 paragraph point about applied cryptography?

Comment: I believe that would be Dave The Laser Unicorn.  Come on, it's clever and readable.  I'd pick a laser shark, myself, but ymmv.

Comment: I found it tedious and annoying; I had to skip to the last page and glance quickly over it to get an idea of what he was actually trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can checkout my other post (example included) and get a headstart.

[few characters missing after decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219377/few-characters-missing-after-decryption)

Basically you just need to use CipherInputStream & CipherOutputStream, and that's it! :)